If $1_V + v$, $1_V + v^2$ and $1_V + v^3$ are unitary, then $v=0$.
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the complex numbers
and $v \in \text{End}(V)$. If $1_V + v$, $1_V + v^2$ and $1_V + v^3$ are unitary, then $v=0$.
This is my solution, but I'm not sure it is correct because I haven't used
the fact that $1_V + v^3$ is unitary.
Since $1_V + v$ is unitary, then there exists a basis of $V$
consisting of eigenvectors of  $\text{1}_V + v$.
Let $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\} $ be this basis and suppose they
are associated to the eigenvalues $c_1, \dots, c_n$ of $1_V + v$.
Then,
\begin{equation}
    (1_V + v ) (\alpha_i) = \alpha_i + v(\alpha_i) = c_i \alpha_i.
\end{equation}
Thus, $v(\alpha_i) = (c_i - 1) \alpha_i$.
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
                     (1_{V} + v^{2})(\alpha_i)
                     &= \alpha_i + v^2 (\alpha_i)\\
                     &= \alpha_i + (c_i -1)^{2} \alpha_i \\
                     &= \left( 1 +  (c_i -1)^{2} \right) \alpha_i.
                \end{align*}
Therefore, $1 + (c_i - 1)^{2}$ is an eigenvalue of
$1_V + v^2$. Since $1_V + v^2$
is unitary, then $1 + (c_i - 1)^{2} \leq 1$, so $c_i=1$
Then,  $v(\alpha_i) = 0$ for every  $i$ implying $v=0$.
EDIT: I saw the flaw in my previous proof. This is my updated proof.
Note that $v$, $1_V + v$, $1_V + v^2$ and $1_V + v^3$ are simultaneusly diagonalizable, and let $\{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n\}$ be this common basis of eigenvectors. Suppose ${\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n}$ are the eigenvalues of $v$, then the eigenvalues of $1_V + v$, $1_V + v^2$, $1_V + v^3$ are $1+\lambda_i$, $1 + \lambda^2_i$ and $1 + \lambda^3_i$, respectively, which have to be of modulus 1.
Here, I'm not sure how to conclude $\lambda_i=0$ is the only possibility.

Since you are working over $\Bbb C$, we have $|1+(c_i-1)^2|\le1$, and not what you wrote. And that does not imply $c_i=1$.

Can you tell us where you found this interesting exercise?

Your approach reduces to the following problem:

If a complex number $\lambda$ satisfies $\left\vert{1 + \lambda}\right\vert = \left\vert{1 + \lambda^{2}}\right\vert = \left\vert{1 + \lambda^{3}}\right\vert = 1$ then $\lambda = 0$.

Suppose on the contrary that $\lambda \ne 0$ then $\lambda = r (\cos\theta + \iota\sin\theta)$ where $r = \left\vert{\lambda}\right\vert$ and $\theta = \arg \lambda$.
$$
\begin{align*}
  & \left\vert{1 + \lambda}\right\vert = 1 \Longleftrightarrow \left\vert{(1 + r\cos\theta) + \iota r\sin\theta}\right\vert = 1 \Longleftrightarrow r^{2} + 2r\cos\theta = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \cos\theta = -\frac{r}{2} \\
  & \left\vert{1 + \lambda^{3}}\right\vert = 1 \Longleftrightarrow \left\vert{(1 + r^{3}\cos(3\theta)) + \iota r^{3}\sin(3\theta)}\right\vert = 1 \Longleftrightarrow r^{6} + 2r^{3}\cos(3\theta) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \cos(3\theta) = \frac{-r^{3}}{2}
\end{align*}
$$
Substitute to the identity $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^{3}(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)$, then solve for $r$, we obtain $r = 0$, which is a contradiction. Hence $\lambda = 0$.

You don’t actually use the assumption $\lambda \neq 0$, neither do you need to use $\vert 1+\lambda^2\vert =0$ (it’s enough to substitute $\cos\theta =-\frac{r}{2}$ in the equation involving $\cos 3\theta$).

@Plop I did use it. Because $\lambda\ne 0$, $r \ne 0$ and $\arg \lambda$ is well-defined. But you are right that I don't need $\left\vert{1 + \lambda^{2}}\right\vert = 1$. I updated the proof.

If $\lambda =0$, then $\lambda=0(\cos 43 + i\sin 43)$, that’s what I meant.

@Plop Wait, why is 43 here?

Why not? You could rephrase your argument by saying: let $\alpha$ be any complex of modulus $1$ such that $\lambda = \vert \lambda\vert \alpha$, write $\alpha = a+ib$ and deduce things on $a$. I think the argument would be « purer ». But it might just be a matter of taste.
